# Windows 8.1 WLAN icon at taskbar not responding occasionally

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, connection, taskbar, notification-area

I am using Windows 8.1. A strange problem i am facing from long ago since Windows 7. I have Intel Wireless N-1000 WLAN Adapter in laptop. Its working great and satisfactory for using WiFI networks. But sometimes when i click the WiFi icon in the task bar/notification area, the ICON DOES NOT WORK/ NOTHING HAPPENS mean it DOES NOT open Network charms bar where i can disconnect/ connect to different WLAN Networks.

Its quit frustrating. To solve this problem (for the time being) i have to perform a tedious task. I have to go to Device Manager and Disable WLAN adapter and then re-enable it. Then it works. The later at some time, the same problem comes again.

I have tried solutions mentioned in some blogs and websites like:

1. Unchecked Options of "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save Power" in Power Options tab of WLAN Device Properties
2. Latest Drivers i have from Intel Website
3. Using "Troubleshoot Problems" option present when i right click the WLAN icon in the task bar

Can any network expert help me about the solution to this problem.